# Floor Joist Cracked

Tags: repair, wood, basement, flooring

Crack along floor Joist in crawl space. Another similar on the same joist further down. Major issue or simple fix? Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from the fuzzy photos. Is it rabbeted (notched on the bottom? What thickness is the board? What's the total height of the board and the joist span.

Comment: Not rabbited and it runs the width of house. Is about 2 inches thick

Comment: I doubt it's 2 inches thick unless your home is more than 80 years old. What am I seeing along the bottom if not a rabbet? Just a dirt line?

Comment: "It's the soup of the day." I realize the joist spans the house. How many feet and inches is that?

Comment: I think that's a knot that caused the weakness initially. But how far back does it crack? Does the cracked off section get bigger? And what is the height of the remaining wood? (I'm expecting a number somewhere in the 8-10" range.)

Comment: Also curious about the dirt line to the left...

Comment: Ha sorry I’m sure you can tell this is not my territory. Width of house is 12 feet. Not sure about question about bottom unless pics are fuzzy. All the beams are same as this cracked one.

Comment: Dirt line to left you are referring to is copper water pipe. Does not get bigger but same similar crack about 6 feet down on same piece of wood.

Comment: I didn't mean the pipe. There's a brownish horizontal line that corresponds with the crack. I initially saw that as a shadow in a rabbet. Now I see that it's just discoloration or maybe the crack itself.

Comment: Yes and could be beam right behind it. About 2-3 feet until end of Joist

Comment: There is a metal strap around the cast iron pipe, is that strap fastened to that joist? Is there anything else supporting that cast iron pipe?

Comment: It is fastened to it and it is also attached to other beams. That is what I thought caused the crack.

Comment: FYI, a "beam" is something we don't have in this scenario. Beams are typically perpendicular to joists and support them. I realize that you're using the term in a more generic sense, but it can be confusing.

Comment: If it's sagging you can just use a jack with a post to carefully lift the joist back to level (make a T-bar to cross several joists and lift until they come to the same plane).  You can then sister a joist to one or both sides - drill and lag bolt with big washers and construction adhesive.  Job done.  From the pictures it doesn't look worth the effort, to be honest.

Comment: The cast iron pipe appears to have been strapped to the joist. It appears the strap was secured below the weakness in the joist mentioned by @isherwood. The force exerted by the pipe settling was sufficient to cause the joist to break along the already existing weak line/point. A solution would need to have the strap secured higher on the joist, preferably at multiple locations along the width of the joist, in addition to repairing the joist as J... suggested. You would need to determine if the cast iron pipe should be secured at it's original elevation, or is OK now (a flow/code issue?).

Comment: It would also be a good idea to determine why the cast iron pipe sagged, as it doing so *may* indicate that there's a problem with how it's secured after it turns vertical.

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr It's probably just a localized weakness and not a serious problem.

I suspect that the joist cracked due to 1) the off-color streak we see, which may be heartwood, and 2) the knot. Both are very weak points in the wood that wouldn't normally be a problem, but their unfortunate proximity combined to dramatically weaken the wood.

The outstanding question is whether there's undue stress on that particular joist, causing sag and severe tension on the bottom edge. We can't say much about that through this little hole in the internet.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! Appreciate it. I will have my handyman check it out next time as well. Just moved into older house so checking off some things I see. We had water in crawl space (same area) this week due to heavy rain. Not standing but just wanted to make sure structure is sound.

Answer (score 0):

I’m always surprised how people can look at a structural failure and determine that it’s “not a serious problem.” I have to calculate the load to determine if it’s serious.  YOU HAVE A FAILURE. Do not ignore it.

A 12’ span is not extreme, but those joist seem extra large for normal construction. If they’re more than 2x12 at 16” o.c., then the designer was trying to do something special.

Is there something special above those joist: like a hot tub, waterbed, etc.? Make sure you follow through and have it checked out. At a minimum I’d fix the support for the pipe. That sagging could put stress on other joints.